# How to setup a multi-room speaker system on a mac mini

Tags: macos, mac, audio, speakers

I have a mac mini setup as my home theatre. I would like to connect about 4 sets of speakers to it for a multi-room speaker setup where I can enable and disable certain speakers easily. I have done a lot of research on amplifiers and the audio MIDI setup application on the mac mini. Where I am confused is on how to get the mac mini to see more than 2 channels. So essentially my question is:

If I connected 4 sets of speakers to a 4 channel amplifier and connected the amp to the mac mini, would the mac mini be able to split all the channels into separate output devices?

If that is possible then I can use the audio midi setup to group the separate outputs into different speaker zones.

UPDATE:

I can't upload photos since I don't have at least 10 reputation points so I posted the graph of what I want here:

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/18_f5FT0QxHTK-LARbNTgDAblNU07-jbe892ddTrZrro/edit?usp=sharing

I apologize for the unclear question as I am learning about this stuff as I go. I am hoping to find a 4 channel amp like this one on amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Pyle-PSPVC4-4-Channel-Speaker-Selector/dp/B0013CH7UK/ref=lh_ni_t?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013CH7UK)

Can't I connect two speakers in a series to one channel? So then a 4 channel amp could handle my 8 speakers?

If I can connect those and then have the 4 channels show up in the audio midi setup then I will be all set. I figured out how to mute individual channels of an output device so I will be able to control each zone through muting a specific channel and enabling another. I hope the additional info helps.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question to be able to get a good answer.  One amp will not do what you want, unless you can control that remotely. "4 sets of speakers to a 4-channel amp" bothers me. You mean 16 speakers, or 8 in stereo pairs, or just 4 in mono? Connecting 16 sets of speakers to a regular 4 channel amp would not be a simple task by any means; the amp would need to be built to take them & would probably already be designed for zoning.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this chap's solution? Whilst not identical to your setup, it may provide a few pointers, and he also highlights some pitfalls along the way. In particular, the *configure speakers* section, at the end of the article, refers to assigning the various channels to particular sets of speakers.

I hope it helps.

> ## [Mac OS X Dolby Digital 5.1 with Mac Mini [solved]](http://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/146-Mac-OS-X-Dolby-Digital-5.1-with-Mac-Mini-solved.html)
>
> This is my 2nd attempt of trying to clarify how to get Dolby Digital
> 5.1 output via HDMI. The previous attempt can be found here. All the information I can find on this subject shows that for some people
> multi-channel audio works fine, nothing special is required, but then
> again for some of us this is a pain and its almost impossible to get
> this working.
>
> Here is my setup:
>
> [image: OSXHDMIDigital]
>
> The problem, like presented earlier is depicted here:
> [image: OSX Audio Devices 1]
>
> The Audio MIDI setup clearly displays as Sony TV being
> the HDMI output device. The problem is, that it actually isn't. Here
> is another screen capture of Audio MIDI setup from my brother's
> computer: [image: OSX Audio Devices 2] Whoa! His Mac Mini displays his
> A/V amp as the HDMI destination. Totally different from what my Mac
> displays. The only explanation for this is, that my Yamaha takes the
> TV's spec from the HDMI and proxies it to the Mac and his Onkyo
> doesn't take anything, it simply presents itself as the destination.
> If you'd ask me, Onkyo's solution is much better than Yamaha's.
> Anyway, the amp has to pick up the audio signal to be sent to
> loudspeakers and do a stereo mixdown of a multi-channel signal to be
> sent for the TV. So there will be a lot of processing at the amp, why
> not declare itself as the destination for the Mac. It seems to be
> confusing.
>
> ### The Solution
>
> Here is what I did to get proper 5.1 channel sound working from my Mac
> Mini. The problem is, that I cannot get it back to the broken mode
> again, it simply stays fully functional no matter what I do. There
> must be something going on at the amp end and something else going on
> at the Mac end. For some reason they don't match or they do match and
> there is very little I can do to control it. But anyway, here are my
> steps with Audio MIDI Setup utility:
>
> 1. In the Mac, set HDMI to Use this device for sound output and Play
>    alerts and sound effects trough this device
> 2. Confirm that the speaker setup is correct and click the speakers to
>    confirm that test tone does not output as expected
> 3. In the amp, make sure that the input HDMI is decoding multi-channel
>    audio as expected (Auto-detect or stereo won't work)
> 4. In the Mac, at the HDMI, in Format set it as Encoded Digital Audio,
>    the Hz setting is irrelevant [image: OSX Audio Devices - Encoded Digital Audio]
> 5. This will effectively unset HDMI as output device and set Built-in
>    Output as the output device. It also pretty much makes all sounds in
>    the system non-functional.
> 6. Again at the HDMI, in Format select 8ch-24bit Integer, it will reset
>    the HDMI to Use this device for sound output and Play alerts and
>    sound effects trough this device
> 7. Re-confirm that speaker setup is correct. At this point the test
>    tone should work from the speaker correctly.
> 8. You're done! :-)
>
> This fix and pretty much everything about Mac Mini's HDMI audio output
> is bit fuzzy. Any real solution should be reproducible somehow. This
> isn't. But I can assure you, that now my multi-channel audio really
> works as expected.
>
> Any feedback about this solution is welcome!
>
> #### Update 1st Jan 2014:### The number of channels configured into Audio Setup does not reflect the actual number of speakers you have.
>
> That is done in Configure Speakers. I have 8ch (or 8 speakers)
> configured in the Audio Setup, but this is a screenshot of my speaker
> setup: [image: MacOSXAudioDevicesConfigureSpeakers]
>
> They have different number of speakers! It still works. That's how it
> is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I am trying to avoid having to buy an expensive av amplifier. I want to buy a cheap one and then have the mac mini act as the zone manager. If I could create a multi output device and add only certain channels to it then that would be awesome but it doesn't seem possible the more I research it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have used an Apple TV, With iTunes or similar software, such as Airparrot, you can just throw audio from your mac to surroundsound.